# How do I explore a directed graph (DAG) by visting minimum number of starting vertices?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a DAG (possibly not strongly connected e.i consisting of several connected components), the goal is to find the minimum number of starting vertices required to visit to fully explore the graph.

One method I thought of was to generate all permutations of the given vertices and run a topological sort in that order. The one with the minimum backtracks would be the answer.

Is there an efficient algorithm to perform the above task?

Comment: Isn't the minimum number of **starting** vertices always 1 if you are given a connected set of nodes? If the set is disconnected, then 0.

Comment: It is not necessary that the graph is connected. So NO

Comment: Sure. So if the graph is not connected, you are unable to fully explore it, no?

Comment: The graph may consist of several connected components within itself. So i will need to visit multiple vertices to fully explore it..

Comment: Ah. So the answer is the number of fully connected subsets?

Comment: *minimum* number of connected subsets :)

Comment: Not sure minimum applies to that context.  In order to fully traverse the graph, you must fully traverse each individual set.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please define the term "visit a starting vertex". What you really mean, apparently, is explore a path in the graph. Also, you want to cover every vertex, not every edge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a famous problem called [minimum path cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_cover), it's a pity that wiki says nothing about it, you can search it in google.

As methioned, the minimum path cover problem is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) in normal graph. But in DAG, it can be solved with [Matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29).

**Method:**

Dividing each vertex `u` into two different vertex `u1` and `u2`. For every edge `(u->v)` in orginal graph, adding edge `(u1->v2)` in new graph. Then do any matching algorithm you like. The result is `n - maximum matching`, `n` is total number of vertex in orginal graph.

Comment: @ilikepot I suggest using [Hopcroft–Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

Comment: Which, as a side note, is basically Dinic's maximum flow algorithm. Ford Fulkerson would be somewhat simpler to implement, but also asymptotically slower

Comment: How can I solve it using Dinic's algorithm? I mean isn't that for max flow?

Comment: @ilikepot Unweighted Bipartite matching [reduces to max-flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs) in a rather straightforward manner.

Comment: ok..so basically i have a graph and I run Dinic's on it to get the max flow. I subtract it from the number of vertices and BOOM?. 2 more doubts 1. How do I construct the graph for the bi-partitite matching if I want to use Hopcraft. 2. Do I run Dinics on the same directed graph I have? How excatly to construct the graph>?

Comment: @ilikepot This answer describes the bipartite network that you need to construct. Hopcroft-Karp works directly on that network. A maxflow algorithm would need a second reduction step, which is described in the wiki article I linked

Comment: 'adding edge (u1->v2)'. What is v2? And u1 and u2 have the same vertex number as u in the original graph? Sorry i'm a bit unclear. What can I google?

Comment: For every vertex in origin graph, creating two different vertex in new graph

Comment: Thank you so much. I have implemented it and I works

Comment: For anyone confused as to how to build the bipartite graph, just add a single edge from from the input. If the edge is a,b add the edge a->b. That's it. The algorithm works on this. This is essentially the left side of the bipartite network